# App Crashes when I tried calling a function from recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment

My Application crashes when i tried to transfer text to the adapter from recyclerview, It throws null exception on my Text View variable.

```
class RockFragment : Fragment() {

var value = "daniel"
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rock_view, container, false) as View
    var bandPlayingRock = root.findViewById(R.id.bandPlayingRock) as TextView
    return root

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    bandPlayingRock.text = "lyneth"


}
fun getName(value : String){
    bandPlayingRock.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.bandPlayingRock)
    bandPlayingRock.text = value
}
```

My Logcat Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.TextView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: check if you're giving the wrong id for the textview.

Comment: no, is the first thing that I checked, now I'm triying to change the value of the textView from the adapter but still the same problem

var bandNameText = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.bandName)
                bandNameText.text = bandName

it doesn't recognise the textview from another adapter

Comment: You are assigning ``bandPlayingRock`` inside onCreateView(...) and accessing same variable in onViewCreated() HOW?

Comment: yes and I removed that, but the problem is when I assignate in the function 

fun getName(value : String)

I asignated the parameters from my adapter to take it by the textView, but everithime that I do this send me the error that my textView is null I tried creating a  

    lateinit var nameBandText : TextView, as global var 

and then giving the value with synthetic and even with findViewById but gave me the same problem inside my function but the problem still there

Comment: once the fragment is loaded in the main activity doesent let me give new values to the textView, but this happen only from the adapter when i use clicklistener in my recycler view because from MainActivity I can asignate new strings to the TextView